# SIM808 bluetooth issue

Tags: bluetooth, at-command, uart

I've connected my sim808 module to a [HC05 bluetooth module](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiospbPgv_WAhXBKsAKHW5lAQkQFgglMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electronicaestudio.com%2Fdocs%2Fistd016A.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3XhEyJ5znODV1jZcO6gepP) with SPP profile.
Hc05 UART config is 9600 , no parity,1 stop. 
i'm connecting with these at commands:

```
AT+BTPOWER=1
AT+BTCONNECT=1,4 // I have already paired two devices
```

when i send message `printf("0adch=0&temp=27&hu=14")` via HC05 to SIM808  , it breaks message to multiple parts like below (*I've connected SIM808 to PC via a usb-ttl convertor,so i can see messages on sim RX port*) :

```
+BTSPPDATA: 1,1,0

+BTSPPDATA: 1,10,adch=0&tem

+BTSPPDATA: 1,10,p=27&hu=14
```

Comment: When you say "HC05", what do you mean by that? Is it the [Motorola 68HC05](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68HC05)? Is it the HC05 Bluetooth Arduino module? Something else?

Comment: How it this Arduino related? I don't see any Arduino involved here.